# Relation between baudrate in UART and clock speed

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I am using UART on STM32 board. I started a new project with CubeMx and the first step is to configure clock for UART. My question is what is the relation between UART baud rate a clock type and speed? for example if I want to use 115200 as a baud rate what clock speed should I use ? Is there an equation that matches clock speed with UART baud rate?

**EDIT: This project doesn't work, I guess it's a clock problem because the code is very basic. am I wrong ?**

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  ** This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2018 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t bufferTX[]="ABC\n\r";
uint8_t bufferRX[5];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufferTX, 5, 100);
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufferRX, 5, 100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);    
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 10;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

stm32l4xx_it.c

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32l4xx_it.c
  * @brief   Interrupt Service Routines.
  ******************************************************************************
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2018 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32l4xx.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_it.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/******************************************************************************/
/*            Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers         */ 
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
*/
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
*/
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles System tick timer.
*/
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32L4xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32l4xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles USART1 global interrupt.
*/
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */
/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c

```
    /**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c
  * Description        : This file provides code for the MSP Initialization 
  *                      and de-Initialization codes.
  ******************************************************************************
  ** This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2018 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"

extern void _Error_Handler(char *, int);
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */
/**
  * Initializes the Global MSP.
  */
void HAL_MspInit(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 0 */

  __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4);

  /* System interrupt init*/
  /* MemoryManagement_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(MemoryManagement_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* BusFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(BusFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* UsageFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UsageFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SVCall_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SVCall_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* DebugMonitor_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DebugMonitor_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* PendSV_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 1 */
}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA9     ------> USART1_TX
    PA10     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* USART1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA9     ------> USART1_TX
    PA10     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10);

    /* USART1 interrupt DeInit */
    HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspDeInit 1 */
  }

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Have you read the manual? Here's the [link](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf). Page 799.

Comment: [This answers your question I believe](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207870/uart-receiver-sampling-rate/207883)

Comment: [More useful info](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273172/why-data-recovery-block-needs-to-operate-at-16-times-the-baud-rate/273196)

Answer (score 2):

## The long explanation

First of all, I suggest you to get the reference manual from ST website. For each microcontroller you have 2 main documents:

- Reference manual: detailed description of peripherals contained in a set of similar microcontrollers of the same family. This includes, among many other things, a complete description of UART peripheral, and it explains how to get the desired baudrate.
- Datasheet: information which is specific for one microcontroller, such as pin count, pin functions, which peripherals from the ones described in ref. manual are available and which ones are not...

As you didn't specified which microcontroller you are using, from now I will use an STMF0x1 as example. If you use another one, the chapters of the ref. manual, the registers, etc may vary, but concepts will be similar.

Normally, UART peripheral is feeded with a clock signal, which can be the system clock or another one, and it is passed through a divisor that reduces the frequency to get the desired baudrate. For example, in chapter 26.5.4 of ref. manual it explains:

> baudrate = f_ck / USARTDIV  (for oversampling = 8)
>
> baudrate = 2 f_ck / USARTDIV (for oversampling = 16)

USARTDIV is the configurable value of the divisor, and f_ck is the frequency of the UART clock.

To know the frequency of the UART clock, you can look to the clock tree in chapter "Clocks". You can see that UART can use one of 4 different clocks. In the microcontroller of my example, one of them is SYSCLK. I suggest to use this one if your microcontroller allow it, at least until you are more skilled about this topic.

USARTDIV can be configured with register USARTx_BRR (see chapter 26.8) and f_ck with register RCC_CFGR3 (see chapter 7.4).

## The short solution

You said you are using CubeMx, you can select it graphically without caring very much about the formula of the baudrate, registers, etc.

1. In "pinout" tab, enable USART peripheral
2. In "clock configuration" tab, select clock source for USART and desired output frequency (see image where I select sysclock at 48MHz)
3. In "configuration" tab, select the USART and the USART config window will be open. In that window, select the desired baudrate and CubeMx will try to configure the divisor to proper value to get that baudrate (see image)

## Edit: because OP edition

OP has attached source code and have commented in this answer that code stalls in UART transmit function.

The problem may be related to SysTick clock. HAL library make an intensive usage of SysTick for timeouts and many other things. Ensure that interrupts are enabled so SysTick interrupt (and others interrupts) is called. Also, ensure that you have a SysTick interrupt function in any place, similar to this one:

> void SysTick_Handler(void) {
>
> HAL_IncTick();
>
> HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
>
> }

Also, ensure that you are handling UART interrupts, and that they're enabled. Even in non-blocking mode, I think that HAL library need you to call its irqhandler function to work. Something like this (I don't know if it's exactly the same for your uC)

> void USART1_IRQHandler (void) {
>
> HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&uart1);
>
> }

[image: UART clock selection]

[image: UART baudrate configuration]

Comment: I used this method and it doesn't work. I edited topic (I posted code source)

Comment: You should specify what is not working. Is the program running OK or it stalls in any point? In what point? (use the debugger to see where it stop, you can add infinite loops instead of _Error_Handler). You can also use an oscilloscope to see if anything is being sent. Also, if what doesn't work is that you don't receive the response: may not be because of the delay? If the other device respond immediately, you are not waiting any RX message during the delay.

Comment: Well, The code source is fine, I debugged and I opened a UART terminal (Putty). I don't receive anything and when I write using PC, I used a watch on the RX buffer, no data has been received. Using the step by step debugging, It stops at the transmit function

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Interrupts are enabled and I have this Systickclock function in my project. I tried another solution with HAL_UART_Receive_IT(). I enabled interrupts on RXNE and TC before the while. Still have the same problem

Comment: Added another possible cause

Comment: I updated the post with msp and it files. the IRQ_Handler exists too

Comment: As a last try: once it happened to me that execution always stopped in a certain function, so I though it was because that function. It ended being the watchdog that was always being triggered at that function. Try to disable watchdog. If it's not that, try to test the electrical signals with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to see what's going on.

Comment: HAL - How to make simple stuff complicated? USART and this barbarion library. One of the simplest peripherals.  Looking for the "magic" solutions. 20 lines of the "bare register" code and you are done.

Comment: True. I just found it useful the first time I started with ST, and now I realize that it's just because I had the examples available to look at them. If the examples had been with registers config and a bit of simple code example HAL wouldn't be needed at all even for beginners.